# How do I convert a panorama image into a skybox?

Tags: projection, skybox

I have two panoramas ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUk8I.jpg), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFHu2.jpg)) that are the same but are shaped a little different.

I don't care which one, but how should I go about converting them into a Skybox? I was looking for something like this:

[image: process]

([Image source here](http://gonchar.me/blog/goncharposts/2150).)

How can I do this? I will use an image editing software if I have to.

Comment: Is [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/49192/skysphere-to-skybox-texture-conversion) the same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That software you've linked seems to do what you want, but I presume you would need something that's free?

This tutorial has a blender file that you can use (see section "CONVERT TO CUBE"):
https://aerotwist.com/tutorials/create-your-own-environment-maps/

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tomorrow (It is 4am right now!). It looks promising.

Comment: Thanks! It was easy with a few clicks and helped a lot. I had to fix the coloring on my panormas though to make it look better.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on my project. If you're on Windows 10, I created a utility called Qbit that will export the six faces from the source image. There's a free version available here: https://pragmar.com/qbit/